# Is there a common strategy for renaming files from various locations in same folder?

Tags: filenames, file-extension, long-filenames

For example, I have files named "a" from locations a and b and I put them together into same folder. Is there some best practice, how to rename those duplicates so the old name remains distinguishable?

The content of those files is downloaded via libcurl from various URLs, so I have the host-names of those files, but there can be the same file-name on same host with different path and I know the paths of those files, but the paths can be too long to be stored in a file-name.

I also have Adler-32 hashes of those files, but there can be a file with the same content with the same name, so putting the hash into the file-name would result into new duplicates.

So I want to store the original file-name into new file-name to not lose the original name, but add something to not overwrite the older files. I am not satisfied with Windows systems appending " - copy", because you end up getting file-names like "a - copy - copy", I am not satisfied with Ubuntu appending " (copy)"/" (another copy)"/" (3rd copy)"/" (4th copy)"/...

Maybe just adding number of instance of file-name would be fine, but putting the number at the beginning of the file-name breaks file-name sorting and putting it at the end changes the extension if there wasn't any like "a" => "a.0".

Comment: The key point should be how you design the file name format include file extension. What about new file name = old_file_name_only + '.' + host_name/ip + '.' + INSTANCE_COUNT + '.' + org_file_extension. So you can distinguish the file by reservse find '.'

Comment: How about appending number after initial extension + duplicating extension at the end? Like `filename.ext.number.ext`

Comment: @Eugene But what to do with files without extension?

Comment: Consider a file named 'a' (what you already did); what you asking is how do I rename a file not altering its first and last character (which is pretty impossible for a file named 'a').

Comment: I will probably do it this way: add .<instance_count> before last '.' and add .<instance_count> at the end, when there is no extension. Thanks for ideas. I realized that "a.0" will be similarly strange to "a" anyway.